# Why business objects are made singleton?

Tags: java, singleton

In all the  enterprise/web application i have worked upon, i see Business/service objects(classes containing business logic) are made singleton.

My question is what is the advantage we get by making them singleton ? I can think of only one reason i.e. Service objects are needed again and again and consists of several other dependencies . So it may be bit costly(Time wise) to create these objects again and again. Is that correct ?

Comment: What would be the distinguishing factor in individual instances?

Comment: @Elliott Sorry i did not get your question

Comment: Okay. What is the advantage you get by making them not singletons?

Comment: If someone keep state(instance variable) in singleton even by mistake it will be a issue in multi threaded environment . That is the disadvantage i see by making them singleton

Comment: Business/service objects shouldn't keep state.

Comment: @user3198603: did my answer help ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i understand ideally it should not. But what if some developer does it by mistake or is unaware of it. That's why its safe to create once per request. That's why i posted this question what is the ham ?

Comment: Do you want the code to scale? Because if you don't have any SLAs then there isn't any "harm". If you do have SLAs, try it with your approach and see if you can hit them.

Comment: what is the hit you expect ? Is it memory ?

Answer (score 0):

**Each and every object creation involves some cost in heap memory and we don't create multiple objects for the classes which does NOT hold any state (i.e., they are stateless)**

> Services, Controllers and DAOs does NOT carry/hold any state (data),
>   so we implement Singleton for these classes.
>
> Where as Form Beans/Command Classes/DTO/VO objects hold data and we
>   create one per each request (they are NOT singletons).

**What is the advantage we get by making them singleton ?**

Saving memory, otherwise soon, we might get into "OutOfMemoryException" depending on configured heap size.

**I can think of only one reason i.e. Service objects are needed again and again and consists of several other dependencies . So it may be bit costly(Time wise) to create these objects again and again. Is that correct ?**

No, It is NOT because of dependencies, it is because they DO NOT contain any state (data) and they are costly in terms of memory & time, if we create one object per each request.

In the enterprise/web applications, if you are implementing singleton for a class (such as service/controller/DAO/etc..), then the class MUST be thread-safe.

Comment: ideally Services, Controllers and DAOs does should NOT carry/hold any state (data).But If someone keep state(instance variable) in singleton even by mistake it will be a issue in multi threaded environment . That is the disadvantage i see by making them singleton . So thats why my question is what is the harm if i create those service objects also once per request

Comment: Take an Employee (VO) object which can't be singleton as the data will be different per each request, where as Service/DAO they DO NOT hold any state/data which is modified on per request basis. If you are using any classes (like services/DAOs) in Singleton, you should ensure that they are threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Thoses objects innitialization are expensive! So its better to create just one instance for all the application lifecycle!